# Using R, How to use a character vector to search for matches in a very large character vector

Tags: r, list, lapply

I have a vector of city names:

```r
Cities <- c("New York", "San Francisco", "Austin")
```

And want to use it to find records in a 1,000,000+ element column of city/state names contained in a bigger table that match any of the items in the Cities vector

```r
Locations<- c("San Antonio/TX","Austin/TX", "Boston/MA")
```

Tried using `lapply` and `grep` but it kept saying it can’t use an input vector dimension larger than 1.

Ideally want to return the row positions in the Locations vector that contain any item in the Cities vector that will allow me to select matching rows in the broader table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`grep` and family only allow a single `pattern=` in their call, but one can use `Vectorize` to help with this:

```r
out <- Vectorize(grepl, vectorize.args = "pattern")(Cities, Locations)
rownames(out) <- Locations
out
#                New York San Francisco Austin
# San Antonio/TX    FALSE         FALSE  FALSE
# Austin/TX         FALSE         FALSE   TRUE
# Boston/MA         FALSE         FALSE  FALSE
```

(I added `rownames(.)` purely to identify columns/rows from the source data.)

With this, if you want to know which index points where, then you can do

```r
apply(out, 1, function(z) which(z)[1])
# San Antonio/TX      Austin/TX      Boston/MA 
#             NA              3             NA 
apply(out, 2, function(z) which(z)[1])
#      New York San Francisco        Austin 
#            NA            NA             2
```

The first indicates the index within `Cities` that apply to each specific location. The second indicates the index within `Locations` that apply to each of `Cities`. Both of these methods assume that there is at most a 1-to-1 matching; if there are ever more, the `which(z)[1]` will hide the 2nd and subsequent, which is likely not a good thing.

Comment: I tried it and works great !  Thank you so much.

Comment: If it resolves your question, please accept the answer. Thanks!